# AutomatedTest selenium chromedriver not running after update chrome

Tags: selenium

After update of chrome, I have an issue with E2E automation tests. When I run test, it open chrome website with error: CONNECTION REFUSED after refresh of website test passed. Did you had similar issue? Why I can’ connect to selenium for first time but after refresh it working?

Answer (score 1):

This is a good question for stackoverflow as well.

selenium tests often break because chrome is updated automatically and the chromedriver does not, or vice-versa.

Just make sure the chromedriver you're using fits the chrome version that you have.

http://chromedriver.chromium.org/

Note version 2.43 and chrome 70 are not exactly compatible even though it says they are. If you have chrome 70, I suggest chromedriver 2.42.

I use docker which I manually maintain to avoid automated chrome updates, and I use protractor which has webdriver tool where I can tell it to freeze the chromedriver version. 
So nothing gets updated unless I say so, and it's been working well for a year and a half now.

Comment: To summarize your good advice: "Use fixed dependencies, even when it's the browser, and update them in a controlled manner" :)